# Android opengles scrolling solution

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Before I just modified the Vertex Array to implement "scrolling" of a tiled map but since android uses buffers I cannot use that method anymore. I am using gluOrtho2D for my projection and was wondering what would be the best method to achieve "scrolling". Do I use gluOrtho2D, gluLookAt, or glTranslatef? Is there another option that I do not know of?

Comment: I don't know the best method, but you could reinsert into the buffers.

Comment: Someone told me that wasn't a good idea. Right now I am dealing with using gluLookAt().